# Cream cheese frosting split. Is it still safe for consumption?

Tags: icing

As I was making cream cheese frosting, it split and curdled a bit . Can I still use it for icing the cake . It tastes fine.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it split while mixing, and all of the ingredients were fresh individually, yes it is safe.  You can use it, although it may be unsightly.